# Can I await promise resolution (HTTP request) before exporting a variable in NodeJS module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I need to use an **asynchronously computed value** in a synchronous script which I cannot make async.

If I write a module to make the HTTP request and calculate the value, when I require / import it will return a Promise:

```
// sync-script.js
const getCurrencyConversion = require('./get-currency-conversion')
getCurrencyConversion().then(result => console.log('Well too late now'))
```

Can I design my async module to await the HTTP response and return a value instead of a Promise? Should I?

I'm looking to be able to:

```
// sync-script.js
const getCurrencyConversion = require('./get-currency-conversion')
const myComputedValue = getCurrencyConversion(42)
// do sync stuff with it from here on out
```

Blocking wouldn't bother me in my little script, it makes sense to wait for the request before proceeding.

But I would like to better understand how to deal with situations like these. My current understanding is once you go async you can never "go back". The sync script needs to support async or it won't work.

Comment: what's wrong with having the whole script run inside `.then` - I mean, everything inside `.then` will *"run sync"*

Comment: I can't do that, it's a [`.scas.js`](https://github.com/slavahatnuke/scas/) file, just `module.exports = { // scas stuff }`. To use `myComputedValue` inside a pipe function that transforms input it needs to be... pre-computed at that point.

Comment: No, you can't make `export` wait for an asynchronous operation to complete.  The best you can do is to export a promise and then use `.then()` on that promise in the script that wants to consume the value.  There is no way to turn an async value into a sync value in Javascript.  Can't do it.

Comment: The only work-around I've seen is to fetch the async value in another node.js program and use one of the child_process `sync` options like `child_process.spawnSync()` to run that other program.  This technically allows you to do networking in a sync way.  Obviously not recommended for a server process, but can be done for your own single user script.

Comment: Or, you fetch the async value on startup and you somehow don't start the sync part of your script until after you've retrieved the async value so the sync part can just run (already having the async value available).  You don't share any context of this sync part so we can't help you very well with how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Promises return **Promise** not a **Value**

Also, When you assigned **getCurrencyConversion** to **myComputedValue** you actually assigned the promise which is pending because when you define a variable like myComputedValue it will assign immediately so Javascript will not wait. That why javascript fast

Answer (score -4):

you can make  your code  async using Promises 
you shuld just wrap it into promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap the code in a promise ... just put everything in the script inside the `.then`

Comment: @JaromandaX Putting everything inside the sync script inside the `.then` would be great but I can't do that. I'm wondering if I can do something from the imported module side, where I have control.

Comment: @Leeroy - not if you want the result to remain asynchronous - again, without context, I cant' see why you couldn't put everything inside `.then`

Answer (score -4):

You can create a async function and get the values before proceeding to the next step.
For more info go through this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
if it's a promise it will return that otherwise the value itself.

```js
const getCurrencyConversion = require('./get-currency-conversion')
const myComputedValue = async()=> await getCurrencyConversion(42);
console.log('value is',myComputedValue)
```

Comment: wont `myComputedValue` simply be a **FUNCTION** ? (hint: yes, it will)